# gstreamer pipeline from cam to file C code ends up with empty output file

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I have an USB camera. I have working terminal commands to record or display fullHD video and to save one 4k image. I would like to handle it all via C++ app. If we will concentrate on the video-saving:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=900! image/jpeg, width=1920, height=1080, io-mode=4 ! imxvpudec ! imxvpuenc_mjpeg ! avimux ! filesink location=/mnt/ssd/test.avi`

will save 900frames (aka 30s) of video. I would like to have C++ code to record indefinetly (in future maybe in hour-long segments) until I (the app) tell it to end.

I came up with

```cpp
   struct {
       GstElement *pipeline_sink, *source, *appsink;
       GstElement *pipeline_src, *appsrc, *decoder, *mux, *sink, *encoder;
   } usbCam::mGstData;

int usbCam::gstInit(){
   GstCaps *caps;
   GstStateChangeReturn ret;

   // Initialize GStreamer
   if (!gst_is_initialized()) {
       setenv("GST_DEBUG", ("*:" + std::to_string(3)).c_str(), 1);
       gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);
   }
   // Create the elements
   mGstData.source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
   g_object_set (mGstData.source, "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);
   mGstData.pipeline_sink = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_sink");


   caps = gst_caps_new_any();
   gst_app_sink_set_caps(GST_APP_SINK(mGstData.appsink), caps);
   gst_caps_unref (caps);

   gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals(GST_APP_SINK(mGstData.appsink), true);

   // Build the pipeline
   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (mGstData.pipeline_sink), mGstData.source, mGstData.appsink, NULL);

   if (gst_element_link_many(mGstData.source, mGstData.appsink, NULL) != TRUE) {
       g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
       gst_object_unref (mGstData.pipeline_sink);
       return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int usbCam::videoStart(){
       GstCaps *caps;
       GstStateChangeReturn ret;


       if (!mGstData.pipeline_sink || !mGstData.source) {
           g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
           return -1;
       }


       mGstData.appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "appsrc");
       mGstData.decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("imxvpudec", "transform_enc");
       mGstData.mux = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
       mGstData.sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "sink");

       g_object_set (mGstData.sink, "location", "/mnt/ssd/videoTest.avi", NULL);

       mGstData.pipeline_src = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_src");

       if (!mGstData.pipeline_src || !mGstData.appsrc || !mGstData.decoder || !mGstData.mux || !mGstData.sink) {
         g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
         return -1;
       }
       caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("image/jpeg",
                    "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,
                    "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080,
                    "io-mode", G_TYPE_INT, 4,
                    NULL);
       gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(mGstData.appsrc), caps);
       gst_caps_unref (caps);

       gst_app_src_set_duration(GST_APP_SRC(mGstData.appsrc), GST_TIME_AS_MSECONDS(80)); 
  gst_app_src_set_stream_type(GST_APP_SRC(mGstData.appsrc), GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM);
       gst_app_src_set_latency(GST_APP_SRC(mGstData.appsrc), -1, 0);

       gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (mGstData.pipeline_src), mGstData.appsrc, mGstData.decoder, mGstData.sink, NULL);

       if (gst_element_link_many(mGstData.appsrc, mGstData.decoder, mGstData.sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
         g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
         gst_object_unref (mGstData.pipeline_src);
         return -1;
       }

       ret = gst_element_set_state (mGstData.pipeline_src, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

       if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
         g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
         gst_object_unref (mGstData.pipeline_src);
         return -1;
       }

       return 0;
}

int usbCam::videoEnd(){
{
   gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(mGstData.appsrc));
   usleep(500000);
   gst_element_set_state (mGstData.pipeline_src, GST_STATE_NULL);
   gst_object_unref (mGstData.pipeline_src);
   return 0;
}
```

Now, this code runs. No error in the output, one warning though:

`(GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:51:34.132: g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GstSplitMuxSink' has no property named 'h}\x9fe h\xe6a_no_\xc1')`
.
What actually bothers me is the output file. It is created, but it is an empty file with 0b size. Can anyone point me in the direction of the proper fix?

Edit: Today I came up with two other attempts. The firs one is not that different from the one already posted here. The second gives me pipeline with wrong parameters (different FPS) and I am unable to correctly stop it so that the file have correct EOF.

```cpp
     GstElement *pipeline;
     GstBus *bus;
     GstMessage *msg;

     std::string command = "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! image/jpeg, width=1920, height=1080, io-mode=4 ! imxvpudec ! imxvpuenc_mjpeg ! avimux ! filesink location = /mnt/ssd/testPipeline.avi";
     /* Build the pipeline */

     pipeline =
         gst_parse_launch
         (command.c_str(),
         NULL);

     /* Start playing */
     gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

     /* Wait until error or EOS */
     bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
     msg =
         gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GstMessageType(
         GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

     /* Free resources */
     if (msg != NULL)
       gst_message_unref (msg);
     gst_object_unref (bus);
     gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
     gst_object_unref (pipeline);
```

EDIT2:

OK now my code looks like this:

```cpp
GstElement *pipeline;
GstElement *tee; //in the future I would like to save video and images AND stream or use thi pipeline data internally.
void gstFail(const gchar* message){
    g_printerr(message);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return;
}
void videoStart(std::string path){
    if (!gst_is_initialized()) {
        setenv("GST_DEBUG", ("*:" + std::to_string(3)).c_str(), 1);
        gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    GstCaps *caps;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstElement *source, *muxer, *sink;
    source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
    g_object_set (source, "device", mVideoDevice.toStdString().c_str(), NULL);

    muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
    tee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", "tee");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "sink");

    g_object_set (sink, "location", path.c_str(), NULL);
    
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_src");

    if (!pipeline || !source || !muxer || !sink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return;
    }
    caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("image/jpeg",
                 "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,
                 "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080,
                 "io-mode", G_TYPE_INT, 4,
                 "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                 "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1,1,
                 "interlace-mode", G_TYPE_STRING, "progresive",
                 NULL);


    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, muxer,tee, sink, NULL);
    if (gst_element_link_filtered(source, muxer, caps) != TRUE) {
      gst_caps_unref (caps);
      gstFail("Elements could not be linked or caps set.\n");
      return;
    }
    gst_caps_unref (caps);
    if (gst_element_link_many(muxer,tee, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
        gstFail("Elements could not be linked or caps set.\n");
        return;
    }
    ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
      gstFail("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
      return;
    }
   return;
}

void videoEnd(void)
{
    GstMessage *message = gst_message_new_eos(&pipeline->object);
    gst_bus_post(pipeline->bus, message);
    /* Free resources */
    if (message != NULL)
      gst_message_unref (message);
    gst_element_change_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_CHANGE_PLAYING_TO_PAUSED);
    gst_element_change_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_CHANGE_PAUSED_TO_READY);

    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
}
void takeImage(std::string path){
        GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make("multifilesink", "multifilesink");
        g_object_set (sink, "location", path.c_str(), NULL);
        gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), sink, NULL);
        if (gst_element_link_many(tee, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
            gstFail("Elements could not be linked or caps set.\n");
            return;
        }
        return;
}
```

This saves the video ALMOST ok (VLC does not display correct lenght. But when I see the video file properties via Nautilus in Ubuntu the correct lenght is displayed and the video is playable). It does not save the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's how I solved it: my initial pipeline is split with tee element into two sinks: the original sink that saves the video and appsink. In the callback functuion for the appsink I create new pipeline and push the frame any time I want to save the image. Basically:

```cpp
...
int saveSampleFromAppsinkJpeg( GstSample *sample){
   if (!shouldSaveImage) {
       return -2;
   }
   if (capturing){
       return -3;
   }
   std::thread([=]{
       capturing = true;
       GstStateChangeReturn ret;

       GstElement *appsrc = gst_element_factory_make ("appsrc", "appsrc");
       GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("multifilesink", "sink");

       g_object_set (sink, "location", "some/path", NULL);

       GstElement *pipeline_img = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_img");

       if (!pipeline_img || !appsrc || !sink) {
         g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
         capturing = false;
         return -1;
       }
       gst_app_src_set_caps(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), caps);
       gst_app_src_set_duration(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), GST_TIME_AS_MSECONDS(80)); // TODO 80
       gst_app_src_set_stream_type(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM);
       gst_app_src_set_latency(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), -1, 0);

       gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline_img), appsrc, sink, NULL);

       if (gst_element_link_many(appsrc, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
         g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
         gst_object_unref (pipeline_img);
         capturing = false;
         return -1;
       }

       ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline_img, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
       if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
         g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
         gst_object_unref (pipeline_img);
         capturing = false;
         return -1;
       }

       //push the image in the pipeline
       GstFlowReturn status = GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK;
       status = gst_app_src_push_sample(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc), sample);
       if (status !=  GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK) g_printerr ("Sample for saving image not pushed.\n");
       status = gst_app_src_end_of_stream(GST_APP_SRC(appsrc));
       if (status !=  GstFlowReturn::GST_FLOW_OK) g_printerr ("EOS for saving image not pushed.\n");

       //end the pipeline
       usleep(500000); // Important
       GstMessage *message = gst_message_new_eos(&pipeline_img->object);
       gst_bus_post(pipeline_img->bus, message);
       /* Free resources */
       if (message != NULL)
         gst_message_unref (message);
       gst_element_set_state (pipeline_img, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
       gst_element_set_state (pipeline_img, GST_STATE_NULL);
       gst_object_unref (pipeline_img);
       shouldSaveImage = false;
       capturing = false;
       return 1;
   }).detach();
   return 1;
}

static GstFlowReturn new_sample_jpeg(GstElement * elt)
{
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstMemory *memory;

    GstFlowReturn ret = GST_FLOW_OK;

    // get the sample from appsink
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);
    if (buffer != NULL) {
        memory = gst_buffer_get_memory (buffer, 0);
        if (memory != NULL) {
            //now all data are image data. If image wanted->image save!
            if (wantToSave) saveSampleFromAppsinkJpeg(sample);
         }
    ...
     }
}
void startVideo(){
    if (!gst_is_initialized()) {
        setenv("GST_DEBUG", ("*:" + std::to_string(3)).c_str(), 1);
        gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstElement *source, *muxer, *sink, *queue_rcr, *queue_app, *appsink;
    source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
    g_object_set (source, "device", "/dev/video1", NULL);

    muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("avimux", "avimux");
    tee = gst_element_factory_make("tee", "tee");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make ("filesink", "sink");
    queue_rcr = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "record_queue");
    queue_app = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "app_queue");

    appsink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "appsink");
    g_object_set (sink, "location", path.toStdString().c_str(), NULL);

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline_src");

    if (!pipeline || !source || !muxer || !sink || !queue_rcr || !appsink) {
      g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
      return;
    }
    caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("image/jpeg",
                 "width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,
                 "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080,
                 "io-mode", G_TYPE_INT, 4,
                 "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1,
                 "pixel-aspect-ratio", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 1,1,
                 "interlace-mode", G_TYPE_STRING, "progresive",
                 NULL);


    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, muxer,tee, sink,queue_rcr, appsink, queue_app, NULL);
    if (gst_element_link_filtered(source, tee, caps) != TRUE) {
     //failhandling
    }
    if (gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_rcr, muxer, sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
     //failhandling
    }
    if (gst_element_link_many(tee, queue_app, appsink, NULL) != TRUE) {
     //failhandling
    }
    gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals(GST_APP_SINK(appsink), true);
    g_signal_connect (appsink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK (new_sample_jpeg));
    ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
     //failhandling
    }

    // Start playing
    recording = true;
   return;
}
```